# Input string was not in a correct format when doing string comparison

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to evaluate if a user account equals a certain string that it does not continue. For example, if the user account is AMTEST or PMTEST that it does not execute the code in the if statement. Using the code below I am getting the error that "Input string was not in a correct format."

Something wrong with my syntax?

```
If UserAccount <> "AMTEST" Or "PMTEST" Or "TESTUSER" Then
    ' do something
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use this syntax:

```
If UserAccount <> "AMTEST" AndAlso UserAccount <> "PMTEST" AndAlso UserAccount <> "TESTUSER" Then

End If
```

easier to read and to maintain would be this approach:

```
Dim testAccs = { "AMTEST", "PMTEST", "TESTUSER" }
If Not testAccs.Contains( UserAccount ) Then

End If
```

Comment: Thank you, now I don't get an error but for some reason it is still executing the code in the if statement if UserAccount = "AMTEST" shouldn't it not execute?

Comment: @user1342164: note that i've edited my answer right before you've posted your comment. Are you sure that there is no space or other invisible character or that it's actually `Amtest` instead of `AMTEST`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to evaluate every part of the statement. What the if you wrote is basicly saying is "If the value of UserAccount is not 'AMTEST' OR If the string 'PMTEST' = true OR if 'TESTUSER' = true"

the correct way to do this would be:

```
If UserAccount <> "AMTEST" Or UserAccount <> "PMTEST" Or UserAccount <> "TESTUSER" Then
    Excecute code
END if
```

Another way to write does not equal that is very often used would be != instead of <>

Comment: this wont actually achieve what the OP is after, you need the `AndAlso` as suggested by @Tim Schmenlter above

Comment: **Another way to write does not equal that is very often used would be != instead of <>** not important because this is [VB.net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6.aspx), [not C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx)